# Check if array is sorted using O(1)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Is it possible to check (in Java) if an array **is sorted or not** with `O(1)` worst time complexity?

Comment: You need to examine all elements, so obviously the answer is no. Complexity is O(n).

Comment: @Olivier umm even with recursion?

Comment: Recursion (at least in this case) implies a number of calls that depends upon the input data, thus that's not O(1) even "with recursion". You should probably gather more information about the complexity of an algorithm, O(1) may not mean what you think it means (and also recursion).

Comment: Recursion or not, you still need to inspect *every* element (in the worst case) to answer the question.

Comment: Imagine that the array is sorted except one (arbitrary) item. To find out that the array actually is not sorted (i.e. to find the *odd* item) we have to check all the items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to have a correct algorithm with better than `O(n)` complexity.
Let's *prove it by contradiction*. If we are given an algorithm with better than `O(n)`
complexity we can provide a test array

```
{1, 2, 3, ..., n}
```

where `n` is *large enough* so the algorithm has to *skip* some items (note, that
if algorithm inspects *all* items it has at least `O(n)` time complexity). If
algorithm returns `false` it's incorrect; if it returns `true` we have to create
one more test. Let `m` be the item which is not inspected:

```
{1, 2, 3, ... m - 1, m, m + 1,... n}
                     ^
Not inspected by the algorithm.
```

Let's create the test array as it was before but change `m` into `n + 1` (or `1` if `m == n`)

```
{1, 2, 3, ..., m - 1, n + 1, m + 1, ... n}
                        ^
           we changed m into n + 1
```

Since `m` is *not* inspected, the algorithm returns `true` which is now incorrect. So the arbitrary algorithm with time complexity better than `O(n)` is incorrect, or put it in different way: there are no correct algorithms with better than `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggest, since you need to access all of the N array elements, you end up with O(N) complexity. But this is true only when the accesses take place sequentially. If you have N processors at your disposal, you can access all elements in one go and get O(1) complexity. But this is just a theoretical dream. Still, in practice today, most computers sport many cores, and most languages offer parallel constructs. For example, Java has parallel streams. So you will never reach O(1), but you may do better than O(N).

Comment: If you have a fixed number of processors at your disposal (which is always the case in practice, and certainly this is the case in Java parallel streams) your algorithm will still be O(N). Only if the number of processors (hardware) would somehow depend on the input, you may be able to do better.

Comment: @Hopje. A physical computer has limitations in the amount of memory and the number of processors. However, that does not prevent us from doing Big-O time analyses of algorithms. In this case, I compared a sequential version of an algorithm with a parallel. There is a consensus, I think, that it is O(N) in the sequential case. In the parallel case, we disagree. You say it is O(N) also in that case. I say it is O(1) if there are N processors because Big-O is about asymptotic behavior. If N can go to infinity in terms of memory, it can so also in terms of processors.

Comment: If you have 20 (or 50, or 1000) processors, you can process the list 20 (or 50, or 1000) times as fast, but that is a constant factor, so it's still O(N). Sure, if the number of processors depends on the input somehow (a list of length 1 is processed with 1 processor, a list of length 1000 is processed with 1000 processors, etc) then it could maybe be O(1), depending on the exact formalism, but that model of computation is not very useful anymore for any practical application.

Comment: @Hoopje. I make a final attempt to explain my position. The Big-O measure is asymptotic (N goes to infinity). That means it transcends the limitations of any physical computer. Memory is assumed to be infinite, as is the number of processors. If one does not accept that, the algorithm in question is not even O(N) in the sequential case. It is O(1) because the array has a constant size, limited by available memory. Whether a Big-O analysis assuming an infinite number of processors has any practical value is in the eye of the beholder. I think so, especially since I started using CUDA.

Comment: Suppose you have two very large sorted arrays of longs. One is, say, 2GB large, and the other 4GB. Processing the 4GB one will take about twice the time as processing the 2GB array, even if you're "using CUDA". If your theory cannot explain such things, then maybe the theory is indeed not very interesting in practice.

Comment: @Hoopje. First, Big-O is not my theory. Second, Big-O applies to algorithms, and there is none in your example. Or do you mean sorting? Anyway, I do not think we are getting anywhere. So let us agree to disagree. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Big-O is not your theory, but that model of computation where you can do arbitrarily many things in parallel is. Real computers have 4 or 8 or 64 CPU or GPU cores, not infinitely many. But you're right: this is going nowhere. I'll believe you as soon as you give that better-than-O(N) algorithm to the OP's problem using parallel Java streams. Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: @Hoopje. Well, since you made a concluding comment, I make one too: Big-O is a theoretical analysis of algorithms independent of any real computer. A Big-O measure today will be the same in one million years (when computers and programmers alike have changed beyond recognition). Big-O defines some input of size N, lets it grow to infinity, and looks at how the algorithm responds. There are no limits per se on available memory and processors. Both may tend to infinity. That is necessary for Big-O to work for both sequential and parallel algorithms.